# Symfony2 FOSuser non-unique email

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSuserBundle.
I search since two days how I can allow user to have an email which can be already used by someone else.
I want to allow it because some people haves a shared email adress but I don't found which file of the bundle I have to override.

When I am trying to register a new user with an existing email adresse, Symfony gives me an SQL exception : "Integrity constraint violation".
In the FOSuser Model, there is no annotation of this contraint...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to override the FOSUserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml as given below :

```
on line no. 15:  

  `<field name="emailCanonical" column="email_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" /> `
```

should be as

```
<field name="emailCanonical" column="email_canonical" type="string" length="255" />
```

basically

> unique = "true"

property is deprecated to make your requirement full fill and i hope you know how to override this file ..

Now for overriding i m giving below some tips :

First u will follow the documentation given on the 
    https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

and the child entity in which you will override the

> FOS\UserBundle\Model\User class

should be in xml format .

Now lets your child entity class is

```
  <?php

   namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as AbstractUser;

    /**
     * User
     */
   class User extends AbstractUser
     {
      /**
        * @var integer
        */
      protected $id;

   public function __construct()
     {
      trigger_error(sprintf('%s is deprecated. Extend FOS\UserBundle\Model\User directly.', __CLASS__), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        parent::__construct();
       }

       /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
          return $this->id;
         }
       }
```

Now when you generate your above entity in 'xml' format by following command

> sudo php app/console doctrine:generate:entity

It will also generate a 'User.orm.xml' file in

> Acme\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine

directory .

Now you will use a property called "AttributesOverrides" for overriding the basic mapping of FOSUserBundle's model table which is as given below

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-               project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-     mapping.xsd">

     <entity name="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User">

     <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
     </id>

     <attribute-overrides>

        <attribute-override name="username">
             <field name="username" column="username" type="string" length="255" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="usernameCanonical">
            <field name="usernameCanonical" column="username_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="email">
            <field name="email" column="email" type="string" length="255" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="emailCanonical">
            <field name="emailCanonical" column="email_canonical" type="string" length="255"/>
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="salt">
            <field name="salt" column="salt" type="string" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="password">
            <field name="password" column="password" type="string" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="lastLogin">
            <field name="lastLogin" column="last_login" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="locked">
            <field name="locked" column="locked" type="boolean" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="expired">
            <field name="expired" column="expired" type="boolean" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="expiresAt">
            <field name="expiresAt" column="expires_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="confirmationToken">
            <field name="confirmationToken" column="confirmation_token" type="string" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="passwordRequestedAt">
            <field name="passwordRequestedAt" column="password_requested_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="passwordRequestedAt">
            <field name="passwordRequestedAt" column="password_requested_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="roles">
            <field name="roles" column="roles" type="array" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="credentialsExpired">
            <field name="credentialsExpired" column="credentials_expired" type="boolean" />
        </attribute-override>

        <attribute-override name="credentialsExpireAt">
            <field name="credentialsExpireAt" column="credentials_expire_at" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
        </attribute-override>

        </attribute-overrides>

      </entity>

      </doctrine-mapping>
```

If u carefully look at  "emailCanonical" in "User.orm.xml"  file  i have deprecated the property unique="true" which will override as per requirement .

Now just do schema update and your code will work surely because i have done it and it is working very fine ..

Comment: I create the file in app/Resources/FOSUSerBundle/config/doctrine/model but there is no change in the datebase when I check with "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql" and the file seems to be ignored. So I do'nt know if my method is bad or if it is juste ingored.

Comment: You will not create 'User.orm.xml' in FOSUserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model because 'User.orm.xml' is already existed ..

Comment: I know, but typically for overriding a controller or a view we have to create the same file tree  in the app directory and it will be this file which will be use. But for this type of file, I don't know how to proceed, I am searching.

Comment: You will have to override this for which overriding u will have to follow https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc

Comment: k, first override the bundle as <?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}  and then make a file Resources\config\Resources\config\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml and on this file u will write contents all with which are on   FOSUserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model\User.orm.xml and then on line 15 remove unique="true"

Comment: I already tried it and it doesn't work because each config file of each bundle are considered. If I remove the property in the file of the bundle, the change is ok. But It is not the good way to do that, I done it only for check if a change will be apply at the datebase if the propoerty will be removed.

Comment: My problem is so my UserBundle is already using annotation format although it extends of the FOSuserBundle...

Comment: k, u have 2 options ,either change ur entity format from annotation to xml or follow the link http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html .(7.4.2. Attribute Override¶)   Even your bundle has annotation format u can generate your entity in xml ..

Comment: Thank's to you I finally found the good annotations with better key words. This is my annotations put before my class :

 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "emailCanonical",
 *              nullable = false,
 *              unique   = false,
                length   = 255
 *          )
 *      )
 * })